# Consistent OSGi import of 3rd party libraries

Tags: java, osgi

I've been developing OSGi modules but so far I've come across a number of issues when I've had to wrap existing jars. An example of this is the use of the Oracle database driver which, even though I've wrapped the jar as bundle, just refuses to work (cannot find the driver class even though its present). This is just a single example but I've had issues with other 3rd party libraries and was wondering if there's a best practice approach to using 3rd party libraries which works every time?

Jlove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that jdbc uses a class from the java runtime to find the database driver (DriverManager.getConnection). This can not work as the database driver is not accessible from the system classloader (that loaded the DriverManager class).

A way that works in OSGi is to use a DataSource instead: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html . There you simply create the data source using new and this of course works. The problem is that it makes your user bundle depend on the specific DB driver. So the best practice is to create the DataSource centrally and publish it as service.

You can find some more details in my Apache Karaf DB Tutorial (http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2012/01/13/Apache+Karaf+Tutorial+Part+6+-+Database+Access).

Btw. In general this kind of factories are tpyically where libraries fail in OSGi. Every lib invents another and different factory system and most of the are incompatible with the restricted classloaders of OSGi. Luckily most libs are made OSGi ready nowadays. Most times this simply means that you can also call the factory with a concrete object that you can retrieve using an OSGi service.

Comment: Thanks for the info... I've found it very helpful

Answer (score 0):

My preferred approach is not to wrap the library, but to unjar it, add a manifest, and re-jar it. Jars-inside-jars tend to cause issues that are hard to debug. Unjar and re-jar can be automated with a simple ant script.

Also, I like to write MANIFEST.MF manually. If the library being wrapped is small, then it's easy enough to do that. Tools like bnd that generate MANIFEST.MF for you do not always give the right results, and if you rely on them too much you don't know what is going on under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, can you tell me if this solution works as per my example above with the Oracle driver? I use  the eclipse wizard to wrap an existing jar file which extracts the jar as part of the process so I'm not sure it would end in a different result

Comment: Not sure, I've used the Oracle library in an OSGi context before, without much issues. Would you like to post the MANIFEST.MF that eclipse generates?

Comment: Will do... Will be tomorrow now though. Thanks

Comment: Can you report those bnd 'wrong results' as errors on github.com/bndtools/bnd? I am biased but I've seen infinitely more wrong bundles made by hand than made by bnd. Especially the crucial uses directive is hard to get right by hand. And since a MANIFEST.MF is a valid bnd file to boot, I wonder what the problems are. At least bnd will tell you when you make a mistake.

Comment: I second Peter here. Bnd works great out of the box in most cases and in the rest of the cases you have to do some little config tweaking to make it work. I use it with the maven bundle plugin to create my bundles. 
For simple cases like for the DB driver Apache Karaf provides a nice little feature called wrap protocol. You can specify a bundle with wrap:jar-uri and bnd is automatically applied with default settings to it. For oracle this already works.